# List.GroupBy<> error using LInq

Tags: linq, list, silverlight-4.0, group-by

I'm trying to group a generic List<> in C#. The code compiles, but the application (Silverlight) throws the following error (CharOpps is the class of objects in the list I'm trying to group):

Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[System.DateTime,Invoc_SalesDashboard.ChartOpps]' to type 'Invoc_SalesDashboard.ChartOpps'.

Here's the code:

```
var newtemplist = list.GroupBy(opp =>
                        new DateTime(opp.EstimatedCloseDate.Year, opp.EstimatedCloseDate.Month, 1)).OrderBy(opp => opp.Key);
```

I've also tried:

```
                        var newtemplist =
                        from opp in list
                        orderby opp.EstimatedCloseDate
                        group opp by new { opp.EstimatedCloseYear, opp.EstimatedCloseMonth };
```

ChartOpps have a revenue value, and the EstimatedCloseDate value. What I'm hoping to end up with is a list of ChartOpps with the revenue aggregated in the year/month groupings.

```
                        foreach (ChartOpps c in newtemplist)
                    {
                        ErrorBox.Text += "o";
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing us what you're doing with the result `newtemplist`. The runtime error message indicates that you are taking a group and trying to treat it as an instance of `ChartOpps` which is clearly impossible. Show us that code and we can help you fix it.

Edit:

Okay, now the problem is clear. To enumerate the results of the grouping, you need to proceed as follows:

```
foreach(var group in newtemplist) {
    foreach(ChartOpps c in group) {
        // do something with c here
    }
}
```

The result of `newtemplist` is a sequence of sequences, each sequence having all of its elements having the same value of `new DateTime(opp.EstimatedCloseDate.Year, opp.EstimatedCloseDate.Month, 1)`. Therefore, to enumerate this sequence of sequences, you first have to enumerate the groups, and then within each group enumerate the instances of `ChartOpps`.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I updated the post to show what I'm doing and what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Comment: +1, thanks for asking the poster to post the line on which the exception occurred.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I didn't understand the difference between the grouping object and the objects to be grouped. I'll need to study that further - sometimes us self-taught guys doen't know what we don't know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about your class structure, here is a basic attempt:

```
List<CharOpps> list = GetList();

var newtemplist =
    from opp in list
    group opp by opp.EstimatedCloseYear into g
    select new { g = g.Key, CharOpps = g };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the var out of the picture, it all becomes clear.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, ChartOpps>> newtemplist = list
  .GroupBy(opp => new DateTime(
     opp.EstimatedCloseDate.Year,
     opp.EstimatedCloseDate.Month,
     1))
  .OrderBy(opp => opp.Key); 


foreach (ChartOpps c in newtemplist) 
{ 
  ErrorBox.Text += "o"; 
}
```

The error occurs in the assignment of the first element of newtemplist to c.  c is allowed to reference `ChartOpps` instances.  The first element of newtemplist is a `IGrouping<DateTime, ChartOpps>`, not a `ChartOpps`.  The implicit cast in the foreach fails and you get a runtime exception.

Try instead:

```
foreach(IGrouping<DateTime, ChartOpps> g in newtemplist)
{
  foreach (ChartOpps c in g) 
  { 
    ErrorBox.Text += "o"; 
  } 
}
```